# Obtaining coefficients of a summation by solving equation

Tags: summation

I have obtained from some calculations

```
r/(1 + 1.5 r)^5 + (8.16667 r^2)/(1 + 1.5 r)^5 + (
 31.7222 r^3)/(1 + 1.5 r)^5 + (89.4389 r^4)/(1 + 1.5 r)^5 + (
 209.808 r^5)/(1 + 1.5 r)^5 + (429.43 r^6)/(1 + 1.5 r)^5 + (
 762.345 r^7)/(1 + 1.5 r)^5
```

and on the other hand I have a polynomial as

```
 r A[1] + r^2 A[2] + r^3 A[3] + r^4 A[4] + r^5 A[5] + r^6 A[6] + 
 r^7 A[7] + r^8 A[8]
```

How can I obtain A[n]'s by equalizing these two expressions? Solve command?

Comment: `BSUM` is a polynomial, but `ASUM` isn't; thus, how do you expect to match coefficients?

Comment: But ASUM have powers of r so they can match. I have calculated B[n] for case NN=3 manually

Comment: Can you edit your post to include that example, so people know what to expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 8; 
Thread[Array[A, n] -> Rest[CoefficientList[approx8 = Normal[Series[expr1, {r, 0, n}]], r]]]
```

> {A[1] -> 1, A[2] -> 0.66667, A[3] -> 4.22218, A[4] -> 9.02251, 
>    A[5] -> -0.672394, A[6] -> 64.4992, A[7] -> -122.716, 
>    A[8] -> -768.612}

You get a better approximation by increasing the number of coefficients

```
n = 50; 
Thread[Array[A, n] -> Rest[CoefficientList[approx50 = Normal[Series[expr1, {r, 0, n}]], r]]];

Plot[{expr1, approx8, approx50}, {r, -0.6, 0.6}, PlotLegends -> {"expr1", "approx8", "approx50"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. However as you can see the first expression has N-1 terms while the second one has N terms, it makes problem?

Comment: What is of importance is that it is *approximated* as a polynomial of 8, 9, or 100 coefficients. The first expression is not a polynomial, while the second is.

Comment: So can you explain more about the procedure that your code uses?

Comment: I compute a series expansion to get an approximation and determine the coefficients. The core computation is `Series[expr1, {r, 0, n}]`. If you still have trouble, let me know the specific thing in the code that you don't follow.

Comment: Many Thanks. So this is an approximation an the end?! but I need the exact solutions, Can you help me if I give the original paper which I intend to reproduce its results? maybe I have misunderstood

Comment: @Wisdom, " if I give the original paper which I intend to reproduce its results" - that is something you should have done to begin with when you asked this question.

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon Ok, But I asked another question in Math.stackexchage: [See Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437656/clarifying-an-algorithm-for-optimization). Please read the question to see if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative if you want the literal coefficient on each of the powers of `r` (e.g. `A[1] == (1/(1 + 1.5*r)^5)` and `A[2] == 8.16667/(1 + 1.5*r)^5)`)

```
expr = r/(1 + 1.5 r)^5 + (8.16667 r^2)/(1 + 
  1.5 r)^5 + (31.7222 r^3)/(1 + 1.5 r)^5 + (89.4389 r^4)/(1 + 
  1.5 r)^5 + (209.808 r^5)/(1 + 1.5 r)^5 + (429.43 r^6)/(1 + 
  1.5 r)^5 + (762.345 r^7)/(1 + 1.5 r)^5

List @@ expr /. Times[coeff___, r^_ | r, denom___] :> Times[coeff, denom]
```

> $\left\{\frac{1}{(1.5 r+1)^5},\frac{8.16667}{(1.5 r+1)^5},\frac{31.7222}{(1.5 r+1)^5},\frac{89.4389}{(1.5 r+1)^5},\frac{209.808}{(1.5 r+1)^5},\frac{429.43}{(1.5 r+1)^5},\frac{762.345}{(1.5 r+1)^5}\right\}$

Comment: This is what I was thinking about, which is why I wanted OP to clarify.

Comment: thanks but I need the coefficients.